# Windows phone 8 and Unity 5 support for Facebook SDK

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8, facebook-unity-sdk

This is a request for support for WP8 and Unity 5 for the Facebook SDK.
I am a developer wanting to produce games across many platforms, and being able to publish to the Windows Phone 8 store is a big part of my agenda.

Is support for this platform scheduled to be released any time soon? If so, when are you looking to release it?

Also, is there an imminent release for the Unity SDK that is designed to work with Unity 5? I have managed to get the current release to work, but as it is not yet fully supported, I do not know what will work and what won't.

Any information regarding these issues would be much appreciated!

Comment: I can only assume that the reason this has been downvoted is that there is no programming question?
I searched for a way to contact Facebook Re. this issue, and this is one of only two places they say to get in touch via, and there is no email to use. 
I'd rather not lose rep points for trying to get in touch with facebook, so please don't keep downvoting please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**: I ran into this video that explains how the "AndContinue" methods are going away in windows 10 so we can use one single method; the Async methods that already exists on windows 8/8.1 api. Check it out at https://youtu.be/aFVAP3fNJVo?t=23m34s

I was in the same place as you but managed to get it working. When I have time, ill probably write a blog on my experiences.

Here is some of the main code that directly calls on WebAuthenticationBroker:-

```
    static bool isTryingToRegister { get; set; }
    private static string _FbToken;
    public static string response;
    static bool isLoggedIn { get; set; }
    static private string AppID { get { return "000000000000000000"; } }
    static private Uri callback { get; set; }
    static private string permissions { get { return "public_profile, user_friends, email, publish_actions, user_photos"; } }
    public static System.Action<object> AuthSuccessCallback;
    public static System.Action<object> AuthFailedCallback;
    public static string fbToken
    {
        get
        {
            return _FbToken;
        }
    }

    static Uri loginUrl
    {
        get
        {
            return new Uri(String.Format("https://www.facebook.com/v2.0/dialog/oauth/?client_id={0}&display=popup&response_type=token&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}",
                AppID,
                callback,
                permissions));
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerator _Run_ConnectWithFacebook()
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

#if UNITY_EDITOR
        UnityDebugAuthentication();
#endif
#if NETFX_CORE
        WindowsStoreAuthenticate();
#endif

    }
#if NETFX_CORE
    static void WindowsStoreAuthenticate()
    {
#if UNITY_WP_8_1 && !UNITY_EDITOR
        AuthSuccessCallback =  _Run_ConnectWithFacebook_SuccessResponse;
        AuthFailedCallback = _Run_ConnectWithFacebook_FailedResponse;
        UnityEngine.WSA.Application.InvokeOnUIThread(
        () =>
        {
            callback = WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri();
            WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue(loginUrl, callback, null, WebAuthenticationOptions.None);
        }, true);
#endif
#if UNITY_METRO_8_1 && !UNITY_EDITOR
        AuthSuccessCallback = _Run_ConnectWithFacebook_SuccessResponse;
        AuthFailedCallback = _Run_ConnectWithFacebook_FailedResponse;
        UnityEngine.WSA.Application.InvokeOnUIThread(
        async () =>
        {
            callback = WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri();
            WebAuthenticationResult authResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, loginUrl);
        }, true);
#endif
    }
#endif
```

Note how I use WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue for windows phone and WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync for windows 8. This is necessary for their respective platforms. You may want to look into getting the WebAuthenticationBroker which is a Microsoft class that works on WP8 and WSA (im guessing you are aiming for WSA, so am I):-

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.security.authentication.web.webauthenticationbroker.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

You will also need to build a c# project in unity so you can implement part 2 of it which includes handling when the token details are returned to the app. Here is my code sample of App.xaml.cs which was inspired by https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631755.aspx:-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Core;
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using UnityPlayer;
using Template.Common;
using Windows.Security.Authentication.Web;
// The Blank Application template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234227

namespace Template
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides application-specific behavior to supplement the default Application class.
    /// </summary>
    sealed partial class App : Application
    {
        private WinRTBridge.WinRTBridge _bridge;
        private AppCallbacks appCallbacks;
#if UNITY_WP_8_1
        public ContinuationManager continuationManager { get; private set; }
#endif
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes the singleton application object.  This is the first line of authored code
        /// executed, and as such is the logical equivalent of main() or WinMain().
        /// </summary>
        public App()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            appCallbacks = new AppCallbacks();
            appCallbacks.RenderingStarted += RemoveSplashScreen;

#if UNITY_WP_8_1
            this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
            continuationManager = new ContinuationManager();
#endif
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when application is launched through protocol.
        /// Read more - http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br224742
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args"></param>
        protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
#if UNITY_WP_8_1

            var continuationEventArgs = args as IContinuationActivatedEventArgs;
            if (continuationEventArgs != null)
            {

                    ContinueWebAuthentication(args as WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs);
                    return;
                //}
            }
#endif
            string appArgs = "";
            Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.SplashScreen splashScreen = null;
            switch (args.Kind)
            {
                case ActivationKind.Protocol:
                    ProtocolActivatedEventArgs eventArgs = args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;
                    splashScreen = eventArgs.SplashScreen;
                    appArgs += string.Format("Uri={0}", eventArgs.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
                    break;
            }
            InitializeUnity(appArgs, splashScreen);
        }


#if UNITY_WP_8_1
        public void ContinueWebAuthentication(WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs args)
        {
            WebAuthenticationResult result = args.WebAuthenticationResult;

            if (result.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
            {
                string responseData = result.ResponseData.Substring(result.ResponseData.IndexOf("access_token"));
                String[] keyValPairs = responseData.Split('&');
                string access_token = null;
                string expires_in = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < keyValPairs.Length; i++)
                {
                    String[] splits = keyValPairs[i].Split('=');
                    switch (splits[0])
                    {
                        case "access_token":
                            access_token = splits[1]; //you may want to store access_token for further use. Look at Scenario5 (Account Management).
                            break;
                        case "expires_in":
                            expires_in = splits[1];
                            break;
                    }
                }

                AppCallbacks.Instance.UnityActivate(Window.Current.CoreWindow, CoreWindowActivationState.CodeActivated);
                AppCallbacks.Instance.InvokeOnAppThread(() =>
                {
                    // back to Unity
                    //function to call or variable that accepts the access token 
                }, false);
                //OutputToken(result.ResponseData.ToString());
                //await GetFacebookUserNameAsync(result.ResponseData.ToString());
            }
            else if (result.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.ErrorHttp)
            {
                //OutputToken("HTTP Error returned by AuthenticateAsync() : " + result.ResponseErrorDetail.ToString());
                AppCallbacks.Instance.InvokeOnAppThread(() =>
                {
                    // back to Unity
                    //function to call indicating something went wrong
                }, false);
            }
            else if(result.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.UserCancel)
            {
                //OutputToken("Error returned by AuthenticateAsync() : " + result.ResponseStatus.ToString());
                AppCallbacks.Instance.InvokeOnAppThread(() =>
                {
                    // back to Unity
                    //function to call indicating something went wrong
                }, false);
            }

        }
#endif

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when application is launched via file
        /// Read more - http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br224742
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args"></param>
        protected override void OnFileActivated(FileActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            string appArgs = "";
            Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.SplashScreen splashScreen = null;

            splashScreen = args.SplashScreen;
            appArgs += "File=";
            bool firstFileAdded = false;
            foreach (var file in args.Files)
            {
                if (firstFileAdded) appArgs += ";";
                appArgs += file.Path;
                firstFileAdded = true;
            }

            InitializeUnity(appArgs, splashScreen);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when the application is launched normally by the end user.  Other entry points
        /// will be used when the application is launched to open a specific file, to display
        /// search results, and so forth.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">Details about the launch request and process.</param>
        protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            InitializeUnity(args.Arguments, args.SplashScreen);
        }

        private void InitializeUnity(string args, Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.SplashScreen splashScreen)
        {
#if UNITY_WP_8_1
            ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SuppressSystemOverlays = true;
#pragma warning disable 4014
            StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().HideAsync();
#pragma warning restore 4014
#endif

            appCallbacks.SetAppArguments(args);
            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

            // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
            // just ensure that the window is active
            if (rootFrame == null && !appCallbacks.IsInitialized())
            {
                var mainPage = new MainPage(splashScreen);
                Window.Current.Content = mainPage;
                Window.Current.Activate();

                // Setup scripting bridge
                _bridge = new WinRTBridge.WinRTBridge();
                appCallbacks.SetBridge(_bridge);

#if !UNITY_WP_8_1
                appCallbacks.SetKeyboardTriggerControl(mainPage);
#endif

                appCallbacks.SetSwapChainPanel(mainPage.GetSwapChainPanel());
                appCallbacks.SetCoreWindowEvents(Window.Current.CoreWindow);
                appCallbacks.InitializeD3DXAML();
            }

            Window.Current.Activate();

#if UNITY_WP_8_1
            SetupLocationService();
#endif
        }

        private void RemoveSplashScreen()
        {
            // This will fail if you change main window class
            // Make sure to adjust accordingly if you do something like this
            MainPage page = (MainPage)Window.Current.Content;
            page.RemoveSplashScreen();
        }

#if UNITY_WP_8_1
        // This is the default setup to show location consent message box to the user
        // You can customize it to your needs, but do not remove it completely if your application
        // uses location services, as it is a requirement in Windows Store certification process
        private async void SetupLocationService()
        {
            if (!appCallbacks.IsLocationCapabilitySet())
            {
                return;
            }

            const string settingName = "LocationContent";
            bool userGaveConsent = false;

            object consent;
            var settings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
            var userWasAskedBefore = settings.Values.TryGetValue(settingName, out consent);

            if (!userWasAskedBefore)
            {
                var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Can this application use your location?", "Location services");

                var acceptCommand = new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("Yes");
                var declineCommand = new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("No");

                messageDialog.Commands.Add(acceptCommand);
                messageDialog.Commands.Add(declineCommand);

                userGaveConsent = (await messageDialog.ShowAsync()) == acceptCommand;
                settings.Values.Add(settingName, userGaveConsent);
            }
            else
            {
                userGaveConsent = (bool)consent;
            }

            if (userGaveConsent)
            {   // Must be called from UI thread
                appCallbacks.SetupGeolocator();
            }
        }
#endif
        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when Navigation to a certain page fails
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The Frame which failed navigation</param>
        /// <param name="e">Details about the navigation failure</param>
        void OnNavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to load Page " + e.SourcePageType.FullName);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when application execution is being suspended.  Application state is saved
        /// without knowing whether the application will be terminated or resumed with the contents
        /// of memory still intact.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the suspend request.</param>
        /// <param name="e">Details about the suspend request.</param>
        private async void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
        {
            var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
            await SuspensionManager.SaveAsync();
            deferral.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

You will also need the ContinuationManager.cs class and the SuspensionManager.cs class but mainly for WP8.1 Universal. This isnt needed for W8.1 and so you should ensure that you are using #defines to keep them within their own contexts

If you want, instead of calling on WebAuthenticationBroker, you could call on the facebook app directly but I don't know of all the details. You can read up on that on facebook's website developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-for-windows-phone. That method isnt recommended incase the user doesn't have it installed.

Long (rushed) story short, call WebAuthenticationBroker, handle the continuation Event in OnActivated event to catch the WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs object coming through and use the data however you see fit. Be sure to use the following if you want to call any code in the unity side. Note that you can directly access the c# code from App.xaml.cs:-

```
AppCallbacks.Instance.InvokeOnAppThread(() =>
                {
                    // back to Unity
                    //your code here
                }, false);
```

Also note that this is mainly to get the access token. Once we have that, we can make basic WWW calls directly to facebook and get data back from it. The data will be returned as a JSON format (ps this is such an awesome clean format!) you can use the .NET json library to serialize it into a class. I use json2csharp.com to convert any example output into a class which I just parse into the json library.

Comment: Excellent response thank you so much. I will probably be back if I have any problems :P
I'd upvote you but I don't have enough rep points :/ Sorry about that!